# Downloading a large number of files from online directory

Tags: google-chrome, download, mp3

I want to download 100+ audio files from a website. The link to the files is of the form www.foo.com/bar/XXX.mp3 where XXX varies as 001, 002, and so on. www.foo.com/bar is accessible and has links to 001.mp3 and so on. I tried download master extension, but it overwhelmed Chrome and most of the downloads were cancelled.

How can I download all files automatically on manageable batches so that the download is not cancelled?

Comment: Add a question in your post.

Comment: Which OS are we talking about?

Comment: Windows XP/Vista/7 (I have all)

Comment: Browsers: Chrome/IE/Firefox

Comment: I've used [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) quite effectivelly when mass downloading from links on sites. Don't believe it has a Chrome version though

Comment: [GetThemAll](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fvd&hl=en_GB) is the Chrome equivalent to DownThemAll.